# React-native-background timer stop working after 15 minutes when app is in background and screen is locked

Tags: javascript, react-native

My background timer stops after 15 minutes when I lock my screen.
this is the timer for storing data when app is in the background.

`this.backgroundinterval = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(this.storeData, 90000)`

I want to call that function periodically. Any idea how can I covert it to endless process

Answer (score 1):

Android automatically kills your app after a certain time of inactivity so you cannot run a endless process in background.

Now if you want to run a function periodically then 1 solution can be that you initialize firebase push notifications in your app and then send a notification at some intervals from the server this will automatically run your listener in background.

You can read more on it here : https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage

Other than that you can also use module : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-alarm-notification

Using this you can fire some alarms and then listen when those alarms rings.

#### Edit :

For react-native-push-notification you can just use the onNotification callback to listen the notification.

```js
import PushNotificationIOS from "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios";
import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";

// Must be outside of any component LifeCycle (such as `componentDidMount`).
PushNotification.configure({
  // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
  onRegister: function (token) {
    console.log("TOKEN:", token);
  },

  // (required) Called when a remote is received or opened, or local notification is opened
  onNotification: function (notification) {
    console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);

    // process the notification

    // (required) Called when a remote is received or opened, or local notification is opened
    notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
  },

  // (optional) Called when Registered Action is pressed and invokeApp is false, if true onNotification will be called (Android)
  onAction: function (notification) {
    console.log("ACTION:", notification.action);
    console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);

    // process the action
  },

  // (optional) Called when the user fails to register for remote notifications. Typically occurs when APNS is having issues, or the device is a simulator. (iOS)
  onRegistrationError: function(err) {
    console.error(err.message, err);
  },

  // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.
  permissions: {
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  },

  // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
  // default: true
  popInitialNotification: true,

  /**
   * (optional) default: true
   * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
   * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
   * - if you are not using remote notification or do not have Firebase installed, use this:
   *     requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios'
   */
  requestPermissions: true,
});
```

Read more [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification#usage).

Comment: can you elaborate more about how to listening event I when push notification

Comment: For which one firebase or react native alarm

Comment: i am using react native push notification